# How to simplify a nested list in R?

Tags: r, list

I have a nested list like this:

```
nested_list <- list(a = c(1,2),
          b = list(
            c = c(3,4),
            d = list(
                e = c(5,6,7)
            )))
```

I want to simplify it so it looks like this (only one level, nested names grouped using colons):

```
simplified_list <- list(a = c(1,2),
          "b:c" = c(3,4),
          "b:d:e" = c(5,6,7)
         )
```

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This approach has the advatnage of being quite short.  It does not use any packages.  It assumes that the input names do not contain trailing digits:

```
u <- unlist(nested_list)
res <- tapply(u, sub("\\d+$", "", names(u)), unname)
```

giving:

```
> res
$a
[1] 1 2

$b.c
[1] 3 4

$b.d.e
[1] 5 6 7
```

If its important that the names be separated by : instead of . then add this:

```
names(res) <- chartr(".", ":", names(res))
```

Answer (score 3):

I make no claims to "best", but this works:

```
d <- reshape2::melt(nested_list)
> d
  value   L3   L2 L1
1     1 <NA> <NA>  a
2     2 <NA> <NA>  a
3     3 <NA>    c  b
4     4 <NA>    c  b
5     5    e    d  b
6     6    e    d  b
7     7    e    d  b
> d$L <- apply(d[,c('L1','L2','L3')],1,function(x) paste(unique(x[!is.na(x)]),collapse = ":"))
> l <- plyr::dlply(d,"L",function(x) unlist(x$value))
> l
$a
[1] 1 2

$`b:c`
[1] 3 4

$`b:d:e`
[1] 5 6 7
```

Answer (score 3):

I was too slow, but maybe my solution still helps. It is somewhat longer than joran's, but (at least to me) seems easier to understand. (But maybe that is just because I'm not too familiar with the `plyr` package.) I definitely won't claim it's the best solution...

```
# create names for the list
nm <- names(unlist(nested_list))
nm <- unique(sub("[0-9]*$","",nm))
nm <- gsub("\\.",":",nm)

# construct list
new_list <- lapply(nm,function(n) {
   nested_list[[strsplit(n,":")[[1]]]]
})

# apply names
names(new_list) <- nm
> new_list
$a
[1] 1 2

$`b:c`
[1] 3 4

$`b:d:e`
[1] 5 6 7
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd never realized that I can access the lower levels of a nested list by specifying a character vector with the names `nested_list[[c("b", "d", "e")]]`

Answer (score 3):

Another option:

```
nested_list <- list(a = c(1,2),
                    b = list(
                      c = c(3,4),
                      d = list(
                        e = c(5,6,7)
                      )))


ul <- unlist(nested_list)
sp <- split(unname(ul), gsub('\\d', '', names(ul)))
`names<-`(sp, gsub('\\.', ':', names(sp)))
# $a
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $`b:c`
# [1] 3 4
# 
# $`b:d:e`
# [1] 5 6 7
```

Comment: Interesting, I'd never thought of calling the ``names<-`` function directly

Answer (score 3):

I came across a function called [`LinearizeNestedList`](https://gist.github.com/mrdwab/4205477) by [Akhil S Bhel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1533691/asb) some time ago and saved it as a Gist. It seems to do exactly what you ask for:

```
LinearizeNestedList(nested_list, NameSep = ".")
# $a
# [1] 1 2
# 
# $b.c
# [1] 3 4
# 
# $b.d.e
# [1] 5 6 7
```

Comment: Well yeah sure, that'll do! This definitely beats spending 4 hours trying to come up with the slickest answer

Comment: @RichardScriven, I found it a while ago and it's actually a pretty cool (and efficient) function. I haven't really gotten into the habit of writing recursive functions, but I thought this one was cool. And yes, it beats having to do it yourself :-)